# IIS URL Rewrite .html to .aspx

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm new to the IIS URL Rewrite tool and need some help with my configuration (http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite):

I need to redirect all the old product links from an old shop system (using .html links) to our new shop system (using a longer path and .aspx links).

The old URLs are built like this: www.domain.com/[product number].html

I need them like this: www.domain.com/path1/path2/[same product number].aspx

path1 and path2 are fixed, they don't change at all.

I tried lots of different tips (from google and also from stackoverflow), this is what came out (but did not work - I get the new URL, but the product number is empty):

```
<rule name="HTML zu ASPX" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="([_0-9a-z-]+)\.html" />
<action type="Redirect" url="path1/path2/{R:1}.aspx" />
```

Any ideas? Any questions I forgot/didn't know to be asked?

Thanks in advance
Daniel

Comment: Your example works fine for me! Make sure browser is not caching results (Redirects are cached and always little bit hard to invalidate)

Comment: Okay, that was it... Thanks for the hint, really did not think of anything this simple...

Comment: nice:) I added official answer, you can mark it as correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure browser is not caching results (Redirects are cached and always little bit hard to invalidate)